# ymaps actionend - как отключить событие для map.panTo? или аналог dragend от google?

Tags: яндекс-карты

Вопрос по яндекс картам.
Есть ли в яндекс картах событие `dragend` как в гугл картах?

Есть следующий алгоритм

1. Перетаскивание карты (**drag или мышью**)
2. Детект адреса по координатам (**обращение к api**) => .then
3. **this.map.panTo(center)** - передвижение карты на ближайший адрес

Проблема заключается в том, что ymap реагирует на действие пользователя
и на panTo - одинаково. Вызывает событие actionend.

Вопросы

1. Есть ли событие как dragend в googleMaps
2. Можно ли задетектить, что собитие было вызвана с помощью `this.map.panTo` || `this.map.setCenter`?

Пример кода - набросок

```
                this.map.events.add('actionend', e => {

                    const state = this.map.action.getCurrentState();
                    const zoomLevel = state.zoom;

                    this.calcAddress()
                        .then(({ center }) => {
                            this.map.panTo(center, zoomLevel)
                        });
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

В API Яндекс.Карт actionend будет приходить всегда.
**panTo** возвращает **Promise**, подпишитесь на него.